# How do I edit the hotspot configuration for Network Manager?

Tags: password, wifi, networkmanager, wifi-hotspot

Running Arch/Linux with everything up-to-date and I use network manager's built-in hotspot function to share my Internet.

I'm trying to edit the configuration (mostly the password, as I don't like the random password) for the "hotspot" connection. I've worked on both the network settings GUI and the config file under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. Somehow network manager doesn't like this configuration being edited. Every time I change anything and start hotspot again, the edited one will be abandoned, and NM will create a new hotspot connection with default settings and a new random password. How do I tell NM to accept what I've edited?

Answer (score 2):

I've had success editing the `essid` and `psk` fields in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot` and then restarting NetworkManager with `sudo service network-manager restart` so that it reads in the new settings.

It seems that as long as this file is still called `Hotspot`, it will be the configuration used when you start a hotspot from System Settings -> Networking.

NOTE: I've most recently tried this on LMDE, but hopefully it will apply to Arch.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to get the graphical tools to respect the ssid change, I was able to find a way to setup a wifi access point directly like so:

```
nmcli dev wifi hotspot ifname wlp4s0 ssid test password "test1234"
```

credit: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384513/61349

Answer (score 1):

The hotspot configuration for Network manager can be edited from the file `plasma-nm` located in `/home/~/.config/`

```
[General]
AirplaneModeEnabled=false
HotspotConnectionPath=/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
HotspotName=Y4
HotspotPassword=
ManageVirtualConnections=true
UnlockModemOnDetection=true
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have activated *hostapd*, then the password is in /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf.

Comment: I'm not running hostapd. The authentication is handled by NM using something. Actually NM and hostapd can get in conflict.

If I stop NM from managing WLAN and use hostpd it works well. But using NM's built-in AP is just more convenient.

Comment: NM uses the tool [wpa_supplicant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wpa_supplicant) and is passing settings to it at runtime through a Unix domain socket.

Comment: And investigating wpa_supplicant further, it seems to either be forked from or copying parts of hostapd. It has [hostapd.h](https://github.com/digsrc/wpa_supplicant/blob/515eb37dd1df3f4a05fc2a31c265db6358301988/src/ap/hostapd.h).

You're right it's a different binary and uses different config files and may conflict, but they do not seem so different...