# Create wireless access point and share internet connection with nmcli

Tags: boot, wifi, bridge, internet, access-point

How can I create a Wi-Fi hotspot with the command line tool `nmcli` and share/bridge the ethernet internet connection with the wireless access point? Furthermore, how can I start this automatically at boot?

Is this possible with `nmcli`?

Comment: try wpa_supplicant, it's an raspberry-pi example, but you could port it for your system http://raspberry-at-home.com/hotspot-wifi-access-point/

Comment: I'm searching for a solution with `nmcli`, if that is possible.

Comment: I have version 1.0.6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I created a Hotspot with the GNOME Network-Manager. The problem was, that I can not configure the SSID and password in GUI. If you create the Hotspot with the Network-Manager GUI, it creates the file `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot`. In that file it is possible to edit the SSID and the password.

```
sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Hotspot
```

The content of the file looks like this:

```
[connection]
id=Hotspot
uuid=0bf627gd-8e34-48c6-865a-06f898b4y1hb
type=wifi
autoconnect=true
permissions=
secondaries=

[wifi]
hidden=false
mac-address=YOUR_WIFI_INTERFACE_MAC_ADDRESS
mac-address-blacklist=
mode=ap
seen-bssids=
ssid=SSID_NAME

[wifi-security]
group=ccmp;
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
pairwise=ccmp;
proto=rsn;
psk=YOUR_WIFI_AP_PASSWORD

[ipv4]
dns-search=
method=shared

[ipv6]
dns-search=
method=auto
```

I changed the `ssid` and the `psk` properties to my needs. To enable autostart you have to set the parameter `autoconnect` to `true`. Then I restarted my computer because the command: `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` for network restart seems not to work correctly, because in the Network-Manager GUI:

[image: wireless settings gone]

I have no wireless network settings anymore and also the following command worked not before the restart. After restart you can use the `nmcli` command to start the access point.

```
nmcli con up Hotspot ifname YOUR_WIFI_INTERFACE
```

`YOUR_WIFI_INTERFACE` you can find out with the command `iwconfig`.

I used Antergos / Arch Linux for the above solution and found the hint to this at the [ask.fedoraproject.org](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/40383/how-to-create-and-configure-a-hotspot-in-fedora-20/?answer=49941#post-id-49941) site.

Answer (score 44):

You can create a hotspot with the following:

```
nmcli dev wifi hotspot ifname wlp4s0 ssid test password "test1234"
```

(where `wlp4s0` is the name of your Wifi interface).

Reference: https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#Troubleshooting_.26_Tips_for_NetworkManager

Comment: Simplest answer, yet so effective. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, amazingly simple and works great.

Comment: does this do ip forwarding via a (cabled?) connection?

Comment: > does this do ip forwarding via a (cabled?) connection? - Yes

Comment: It does not completely answer the question.

Comment: Does not work: `Error: Connection activation failed: (5) IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.).`

Comment: FYI this answer is linked at https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse

Comment: I can't connect to the hotspot resulting from executing this

Comment: I cannot connect to a hotspot created like this (on my Raspberry Pi 3) with my Android cellphone. (The phone attempts to connect, but times out after a while with the message "Connection to "Testing" timed out. Connection Failed.")

Answer (score 11):

On a Centos 7 it looks like this.

Check if AP is possible at all:

```
iw list | less
```

and search for "AP" among supported interface modes.

Browse your devices to find the name:

```
nmcli d
```

And setup and start your hotspot.

Mind that wifi-device, connection-name and hotspot-ssid are specific to your system.

```
nmcli c add type wifi ifname wifi-device con-name connection-name autoconnect no ssid hotspot-ssid
nmcli connection modify connection-name 802-11-wireless.mode ap 802-11-wireless.band bg ipv4.method shared
nmcli connection modify connection-name wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk
nmcli connection modify connection-name wifi-sec.psk "le password"
nmcli connection up connection-name
```

Check also:

- https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_NetworkManager_Command_Line_Tool_nmcli.html
- https://www.hogarthuk.com/?q=node/8

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old question, but thought I would add my comments as this may help someone in the future.

The whole process is just three commands as @Dzik has correctly mentioned.

```
nmcli connection add type wifi ifname wlan0 con-name local-ap autoconnect yes ssid test-ap mode ap
nmcli connection modify con-name 802-11-wireless.mode ap 802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt wpa-psk ipv4.method shared 802-11-wireless-security.psk 'PASSWORD'
nmcli connection up con-name
```

This will start an AP for you.

To verify, we can use:

```
nmcli dev wifi list
```

Comment: This worked for me (when the accepted answer did not) on Ubuntu 20.04. Unfortunately some additional setup is apparently required for the machine with the access point to also share its internet.

Comment: When I use `802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt wpa-psk` the clients complain that the connection uses WPA, which is not secure, and that I should switch to WPA2/WPA3. When I read the manual for this property it says that `wpa-psk` means WPA2/WPA3. What's going on here?

Answer (score 4):

Just

```
nmcli dev wifi hotspot
```

will generate a password and start a hotspot with SSID `Hotspot-<YOUR_HOSTNAME>` on the default wifi interface.

To show the Wi-Fi name and password (and a QR code):

```
nmcli dev wifi show-password
```

---

From `nmcli dev wifi --help`:

```
ARGUMENTS := hotspot [ifname <ifname>] [con-name <name>] [ssid <SSID>]
                                         [band a|bg] [channel <channel>] [password <password>]

Create a Wi-Fi hotspot. Use 'connection down' or 'device disconnect'
to stop the hotspot.
Parameters of the hotspot can be influenced by the optional parameters:
ifname - Wi-Fi device to use
con-name - name of the created hotspot connection profile
ssid - SSID of the hotspot
band - Wi-Fi band to use
channel - Wi-Fi channel to use
password - password to use for the hotspot
```

Note: You need a DHCP server installed (e.g. `dnsmasq`), or you'll get

```
IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.).
```

---

For the "start on boot" part: see [Autostarting page in ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Autostarting) for an overview.

(The first command here was intended as a comment to [ysdx's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384513/468364), but I don't have enough rep)

Comment: You shouldn't use the hotspot option unless you want the hotspot device to also be the DHCP server.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone have an answer how to do it when the driver does ***NOT*** support AP-mode?

Mine only supports **managed** and **IBSS** (eg "Ad-Hoc")
*(it's a Broadcom proprietary driver `broadcom-sta-dkms`)*

I would also like to use another `DHCPD` to handout IP's instead of the one used by NetworkManager...